# Child menus won't line up with the parents?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I've been messing with this for a while now, and can't find the issue. Can someone else tell me why my child drop-down menus are lining up at the left side of the screen and not beneath the parent? Thank you!

CSS:

```
nav {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  padding-top:12px;
  background-color:#B3975E;}

nav ul li {
  display:inline;
  width:10%;
  height:35px;
  list-style-type:none;
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-size:16px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color:#FFFFFF;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding-right:30px;
  padding-bottom:5px;}

nav ul li a:hover, 
nav ul li:hover > a {
  color:#FD066E;}   

nav ul li ul {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  width:15%;
  min-width:150px;
  height:auto;
  padding:0 1em;
  margin-left:-10px;
  margin-top:31px;
  z-index:10;
  background:#CEBC97;
  border:1px #947A45 solid;
  border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:10px;}

nav ul li ul:hover li a {
  color:#444444;}  

nav ul li:hover ul,
nav ul li:hover ul li {
  display:block;}  

nav ul li ul li {
  display:none;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  z-index:10;
  color:#000000;
  text-transform:none;
  font-weight:normal;}   

nav ul li ul li:hover {
  color:#444444;
  text-decoration:none;}    

nav ul li ul li a {
  display:block;
  text-transform:none;
  list-style:none;
  padding:.5em 0 .5em .5em;
  margin:0;
  z-index:10;
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight:normal;
  color:#444444;}

nav ul li:hover ul li a,
nav ul li ul:hover li a {
  display:block;
  margin:0;}

nav ul li ul li a:hover {
  color:#FFFFFF;
  text-decoration:none;}
```

HTML:

```
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Parent1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Child1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Child2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Parent2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Child1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Child2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this

```css
nav {
  /*width:100%;*/
  /*height:auto;*/
  /*padding-top:12px;*//*Remove this and add paddings to the child top make it align */
  background-color:#B3975E;}

nav li{list-style-type:none;}

nav ul >li {
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 20px 35px;/*add this to fixe the height*/
  /*width:10%;*/
  /*height:35px;*//*Remove this and add paddings to the child top make it align*/

  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-size:16px;
  position: relative/* You need this to fixe the child absolute position*/
}

nav ul li a {
  color:#FFFFFF;
  text-decoration:none;
  
  /*padding-right:30px;*/
  /*padding-bottom:5px;*/
}

nav ul li a:hover, 
nav ul li:hover > a {
  color:#FD066E;}   

nav ul li ul {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
  min-width:150px;
  height:auto;
  padding:0 1em;
  margin-left:-10px;
  /*margin-top:31px;*/
  z-index:10;
  background:#CEBC97;
  border:1px #947A45 solid;
  border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:10px;}

nav ul li ul:hover li a {
  color:#444444;}  

nav ul li:hover ul,
nav ul li:hover ul li {
  display:block;}  

nav ul li ul li {
  display:none;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  z-index:10;
  color:#000000;
  font-weight:normal;}   

nav ul li ul li:hover {
  color:#444444;
  text-decoration:none;}    

nav ul li ul li a {
  display:block;
  text-transform:none;
  list-style:none;
  padding:.5em 0 .5em .5em;
  margin:0;
  z-index:10;
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight:normal;
  color:#444444;}

nav ul li:hover ul li a,
nav ul li ul:hover li a {
  display:block;
  margin:0;}

nav ul li ul li a:hover {
  color:#FFFFFF;
  text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Parent1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Child1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Child2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Parent2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Child1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Child2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Please explain what you changed.

Comment: @Mephoros The final version is now up please check the update and comments.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
nav ul li {position:relative;}
```

replace css

```
nav ul li ul {
display:none;
position:absolute;
width:15%;
min-width:150px;
height:auto;
padding:0 1em;
left:10px;
z-index:10;
background:#CEBC97;
border:1px #947A45 solid;
border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
border-bottom-left-radius:10px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:relative` for the parent element of sub menu's. So that it will related to the particular element. Also remove the negative margin's for top and left. Update your CSS like below.

```
  nav ul li{position:relative;}
 nav ul li ul {
   display:none;
   position:absolute;
   width:15%;
   left:0;
   min-width:150px;
   height:auto;
   padding:0 1em;
   z-index:10;
   background:#CEBC97;
   border:1px #947A45 solid;
   border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
   border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfz7an7f/)